# File system on SD card using STM32MP157D-DK1

Tags: arm, stm32, microcontroller, stm32f4discovery, stm32cubeide

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I am working on a project using STM32MP157D-DK1 and currently trying to create a File System using SD card.
I am not getting the option for FATFS in the CubeMX configuration. (see in picture)

Please help me out!

I am following the instructions of a video on ST’s official Youtube page:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9KDN1o6924

picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/urtir.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think FatFs is included with the STM32Cube MCU Package for STM32MP1.  On the STM32CubeMX Pinout & Configuration Page, drop down the Software Packs menu and select Manage Software Packs.  In the Embedded Software Packages Manager dialog box, on the STM32Cube MCU Packages tab, expand the STM32MP1 row and ensure that the latest STM32Cube MCU Package for STM32MP1 is checked and installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But actually I found out that FATFS is not supported in the scope of the MPUs products as SD-Card is managed by Linux with their own Filesystem. So, this video does not apply to the STM32MP157D-DK1 board.